# What prompts enemies to pillage improvements?

Tags: civilization-6

Numerous times both barbarians and other civs just sit on my tiles without pillaging. I find the enemy pillaging to be a random thing. What prompts pillaging?

Comment: My guess would be when they don't feel like actually taking the city (because of size of their army vs your defenses near/on it) they pillage around it instead. Absolutely nothing to back this theory though

Comment: It seems  they will pillage if it gives them healing and they are damaged.

Comment: @CoqPwner they also seem to be pillaging if they're not interested in your cities (apart from the ones that they are interested in). As in a liberation or reconquest war, they will never pillage the cities they want to retake or liberate and in the case of a protectorate war, they will only ever pillage your lands and not try to take cities. I'm assuming this is due to the war penalties they would suffer. (Of course I haven't tested this thoroughly so I'm not putting this in as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

Scouts will not pillage improvements. They run around looking to find civilizations and, once found, indicate via an exclamation mark above their head (!) that there are sites worth pillaging.

Once notified, barbarians will begin producing units; although which units will be heavily dependent on the era. Typically you will see warriors and horseman charging around as raiding parties. These units are the ones that will actually pillage resources.<sup>[1]</sup>

As for other civilizations and city-states, it's a strategic decision between whether they want to bolster the unit's defenses or acquire the bonus(es)
 from pillaging a resource. The AI tends to bolster defense when an enemy unit is nearby. After all, there is more value keeping the unit alive then recovering whatever bonus is available from pillaging.<sup>[CITATION NEEDED]</sup>

REFERENCE:

1. Civilopedia - §Barbarians

Comment: I do not have any actual numbers to validate how rival civilizations and city-states behave. It would be interesting if someone was able to find anything like this, to add to my answer.